# fast.ai equivalent in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, fast-ai

Is there any equivalent/alternate library to fastai in tensorfow for easier training and debugging deep learning models including analysis on results of trained model in Tensorflow. 
Fastai is built on top of pytorch looking for similar one in tensorflow.

Comment: Keras is a popular high-level API for TensorFlow. Check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious choice would be to use `tf.keras`.

- It is bundled with tensorflow and is becoming its official "high-level" API -- to the point where in TF 2 you would probably need to go out of your way not using it at all.
- It is clearly the source of inspiration for `fastai` to easy the use of pytorch as Keras does for tensorflow, as [mentionned by the authors time and again](https://www.fast.ai/2017/09/08/introducing-pytorch-for-fastai/#why-we-built-a-new-framework-on-top-of-pytorch):

  > Unfortunately, Pytorch was a long way from being a good option for part one of the course, which is designed to be accessible to people with no machine learning background. It did not have anything like the clear simple API of Keras for training models. Every project required dozens of lines of code just to implement the basics of training a neural network. Unlike Keras, where the defaults are thoughtfully chosen to be as useful as possible, Pytorch required everything to be specified in detail. However, we also realised that Keras could be even better. We noticed that we kept on making the same mistakes in Keras, such as failing to shuffle our data when we needed to, or vice versa. Also, many recent best practices were not being incorporated into Keras, particularly in the rapidly developing field of natural language processing. We wondered if we could build something that could be even better than Keras for rapidly training world-class deep learning models.